# Mass Find and Replace in Multiple XML Files

Tags: xml, replace, find, notepad++

I need to do a find and replace on 700+ XML files for the following:

```
<base>7.4</base>
```

needs to become

```
<base>7.2</base>
```

However, the only tool I have to use is Notepad++, and it continually crashes when I try to do the "replace in files" function. Is there another easy way to perform this mass find and replace? I'm not much of a coder, but they're all in the same folder, maybe there's a way I could use a .bat file to run through them? Any advice on what to do or how to write that would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Colette

Comment: Use python (2 or 3, doesn't matter).

Comment: Do you still need an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

You can download a free trial of PowerGREP from http://www.powergrep.com/

Then:

1. Browse to the folder containing your files using the navigator on the left
2. Select `Search and replace` as your action type
3. Input `<base>7.4</base>` in Search box
4. Input `<base>7.2</base>` in Replacement
5. Preview your search, make sure correct files are selected
6. Click on replace

**Enter values and click on Preview**

[image]

**Preview highlights proposed changed**

[image]

**Click on 'Replace'**

[image]

**Files changed**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

XML is annoying to process, because whilst it *looks* like plain text - it actually isn't. It's therefore not ideal to use 'text based' pattern matching to replace it, because ... well, you can break formatting on it. Personally I'd be suggesting:

- Download perl (like activestate community edition)
- Install `XML::Twig` module (ppm install `XML::Twig`);
- Use this script below - specify the files you want to change on the command line (e.g. `thisscript.pl file1.xml file2.xml file3.xml`)

Like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub replace_base {
    my ( $twig, $base ) = @_;
    if ( $base->text eq "7.2" ) {
        $base->set_text("7.4");
    }
}

#iterate the files on the command line
foreach my $filename (@ARGV) {

    #set up the processor
    my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
        #output formatting
        'pretty_print'  => 'indented_a',
        #every time a 'base' element is encountered, run replace_base on it. 
        'twig_handlers' => { 'base' => \&replace_base }
    );
    #process this file
    $twig->parsefile($filename);

    #save the results to a '.new' file. 
    open( my $output, ">", "$filename.new" ) or die $!;
    print {$output} $twig->sprint;
    close($output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's almost just as tedious if I have to specify every filename. And I don't want them to save the results to a new file, just modify the old file. I have a folder with 500 files in it. I just need to search through each file for the <base>7.4</base> and replace with <base>7.2</base>. Not sure if this is easily do-able.

Comment: You did spot that you can set input and output filenames, right? You cannot in place edit on Windows. That just doesn't work, but you can rename the old file first.

Comment: @Sobrique Of course you can edit files on Windows without making a copy. You don't really think Word and any other text editor creates a copy of the modified files :-)